# Using NSArray to populate collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsarray

I am new to **Objective-C**, I have a function which accepts **NSArray** as a parameter now I want to store that array in a local var in my function and then populate collection view through that array, ps I'll also have to update `cellForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method in the same class.

This is the method in the tableView's Cell class. Here I've embedded a collectionView in the cell.

```
-(void)initCellWithSetsArray:(NSArray *)setsArray{

NSMutableArray *setArray = [NSMutableArray array];    
}
```

This is where i am calling this method which accept the array in cellForRowAt tableView's delegate method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        [cell initCellWithSetsArray :self.setsHistoryArray];
}
```

So i need to update the collectionView based on the array parsed in the func when called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I hope you guys get the picture now.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show?  There are numerous tutorials available on collection views.  You can't store the array in a local variable; you need to store it in a property of your view controller as it will need to be available to `cellForItemAt`

Comment: @Paulw11 actually this function is in TableViewCells's class and a collection view is embedded in it the nib file of the cell. so i'm calling this function in cellforRowAtIndexPath of tableView's delegate method and i also need to update collectionview with the same array i am parsing in the function in cell's class

Comment: @Nirmalsinh I've edited the question with some code. Please help if you can.

Comment: Depending on whether you're using a UICollectionView or a UITableView, there are different methods that get called. Unless there is a really good reason to do so, I would avoid using both UI elements in a single view. If in doubt, go with UICollectionView (it's got a little more functionality). The methods below should work, but be sure to also init your UICollectionView properly, setting both delegate and datasource. Post your code if you're unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a property to your cell class to hold the array:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *setsArray;

-(void) setSetsArray(NSArray *)sets {
     _setsArray = sets;
     [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
 numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.setsArray count];
}
```

You can use this array in your `cellForItemAt` method in your cell class.

Also, in your cell classes `prepareForReuse` you should clear the existing array and reload the collection view:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    self.setsArray = nil;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Then you can simply assign the property in your `cellForRowAt:`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCellClass *cell = (MyCellClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"MyCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.setsArray = self.setsHistoryArray;  // Note: This looks wrong; - you should normally use indexPath.row to get the right data for this row
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

## pragma mark CollectionView

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return arrNames.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"areacell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
   
    UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101]; // set tag in storyboard for this label
    lblName.text = arrNames[indexPath.item];
    
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: is there multiple section in your collection view ?

Comment: There are two views e.g View A and View B in the cell and i've embedded collectionView in View A